# Clone Raspberry Pi SDCard to file on Mac OS X?

Tags: sd-card, script, backup

Is there a simple way using Mac OS X (shell preferred) to clone an entire SDCard from the SDCard slot (byte-for-byte)), to a file? I would then want to reverse the process and restore the image from the file to the SDCard.

I was considering using `dd`, but I'm wondering if boot partition / MBR data would be properly replicated. I don't want to copy the *files*, but rather the entire SDCard. Thanks!

Comment: You may use "[SD card backup for MacOS](https://github.com/r-ionescu/SD-card-backup-for-MacOS/blob/main/sd-backup.sh)" as well :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use the following script to backup SD cards on OS X:-

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# script to backup Pi SD card
# 2017-06-05
# 2018-11-29    optional name
# DSK='disk4'   # manual set disk
OUTDIR=~/temp/Pi

# Find disk with Linux partition (works for Raspbian)
# Modified for PINN/NOOBS
export DSK=`diskutil list | grep "Linux" | sed 's/.*\(disk[0-9]\).*/\1/' | uniq`
if [ $DSK ]; then
    echo $DSK
    echo $OUTDIR
else
    echo "Disk not found"
    exit
fi

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
    BACKUPNAME='Pi'
else
    BACKUPNAME=$1
fi
BACKUPNAME+="back"
echo $BACKUPNAME

diskutil unmountDisk /dev/$DSK
echo please wait - This takes some time
echo Ctl+T to show progress!
time sudo dd if=/dev/r$DSK bs=4m | gzip -9 > $OUTDIR/Piback.img.gz

#rename to current date
echo compressing completed - now renaming
mv -n $OUTDIR/Piback.img.gz $OUTDIR/$BACKUPNAME`date +%Y%m%d`.img.gz
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this. I think I'm going to modify this script a bit and use it. Perhaps I'll make it more general and put it on GitHub (I'll give you credit if I do). This seems awesomely-useful!

Comment: @Will You are welcome. All of my code is freely available to all. The code is hardly original and I drew on many sources. The code to automatically identify the SD card is my own - to minimise the risk of picking the wrong one, which would be catastrophic. I did have more elegant code, but it would not work for named partitions and does not work with NOOBS. At least it fails safely if you try.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dd` to backup the drive. The trick is to use the device as the input, not its partitions. Taking an example from the [RPi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=46911), you can backup and even auto compress the information in one action.

To backup the device:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/rdisk2 | gzip > /Users/`whoami`/image`date +%d%m%y`.gz
```

To restore the device:

```
sudo bash -c 'gzip -dc /Users/`whoami`/image.gz | dd bs=4M of=/dev/rdisk2'
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm doing this now with `xz`, but `xz` was the wrong choice as it takes hours. `gzip` will probably be the way to go. Also, you can use `$HOME` instead of  ``/Users/`whoami` ``.

Comment: By the way, is there any particular reason for using `bs=4M` or could it be anything?

Comment: @Will `bs` can be pretty much anything, though the default value (512) slows down copying considerably. Anything from 1M to 10% of your system RAM should be good.

Comment: @Milliways By 'raw disk mode' do you mean when the disk is unmounted?

Comment: Nevermind. In osx you can access disks as raw by prefixing the disk with 'r'. `man hdiutil` search 'DEVICE SPECIAL FILES'

Answer (score 2):

Note the bs=4M will not work on Mac (at least Sierra), use lower case 'm' that will work like "dd bs=4m if=/dev/rdisk2 of=~/Documents/abc.img"