# SD Card Copy failed

Tags: sd-card, raspbian-stretch

I used SD Card Copy utility on Raspbian Stretch, the copied card will not boot.  Error indicates 
end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!

Tried multiple SD cards.

What do I need to do to make SD Card Copy successful?

Comment: what is `SD Card Copy utility` - is it a utility in raspbian?

Comment: Yes, on the Raspbian "Stretch" desktop, under "accessories" There is a utility "SD Card Copy".  It should be a greatly appreciated simple way to make an exact copy of the running operating system.  It doesn't seem to be fool proof, and I am.

Comment: depends on what that program does - copying a live running system is tricky to do right - I usually shut down, then use a PC (windows or mac or linux) to copy a raw image

Comment: @JaromandaX `SD Card Copier` is an inbuilt tool, which works well - even if the OP can't get the name right (or provide any meaningful diagnostics).

Comment: I'm skeptical of tools offering live backups as I explained [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92863/33476). Try again and make sure you don't run any unnecessary programs during the process. Or simply make an offline backup which is guaranteed to work.

Comment: You better should ask "How to successful clone a SD Card" instead of only focus on *SD Card Copy* (what ever it is).

Comment: The "SD Card Copy" utility included in the "Stretch" version suggests that it can copy from the operation system to an inserted SD card that is the same,or slightly smaller size than the source.  This would be great, if reliable.  In my case, it did about 1 in 3 times.  Can you suggest why it might not?  Dmitry above makes a good case, I would like to get a consensus as to if his assessment is the reason that this utility might be valid only randomly.  Thank you.